# CreateRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

When i trying to create room, nothing happens and there is an error in title. What should I do?

If it is possible, than write what specificly should be replaced.

Full error:

> CreateRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking)but not ready for operations (State: PeerCreated). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.

> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

> Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:CreateRoom (string,Photon.Realtime.RoomOptions,Photon.Realtime.TypedLobby,string[]) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:1782)

> MenuManagerScript:CreateRoom () (at Assets/MenuManagerScript.cs:15)

> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:385)

Full code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class MenuManagerScript : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public InputField createInput;
    public InputField joinInput;
    public void CreateRoom() {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 4;
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(createInput.text, roomOptions);
    }
    public void JoinRoom() {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(joinInput.text);
    }
    public override void OnJoinedRoom() {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");
    }
}
I take code from this video: https://youtu.be/IfP5ChmhVFk?t=485
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for photon network

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public static NetworkManager instance;

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to master server");
        CreateRoom("testroom");
    }

    public override void OnCreatedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("Created room: " + PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(" started");
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public void CreateRoom(string roomName)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName);
    }

    public void JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(roomName);
    }

    public void ChangeScene(string sceneName)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(sceneName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby(); instead of CreateRoom("testroom") on the OnConnectedToMaster callback, and then let the players create own rooms instead of everyone always joining the same room named "testroom".

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect, before trying to create or join any rooms.
PUN contains a very simple script to get you into a random room without much hassle. Check out the `ConnectAndJoinRandom` component.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was because the default scene is Lobby when you load in, you need to switch to the Loading scene before you load so it can properly connect to Lobby

basically just switch to the Loading scene before you play

Comment: Thanks for adding that solution. You could make your answer better by explaining how to switch the loading scene before you play, or add some code that reflects that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before you hit 'Play' in the editor, you must change your scene to the one that connects to your server, which is the scene with the function `PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings()`.

After successfully connecting to the server, the function `createRoom()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a few hours i realised a problem with my code, which was; for some reason when i tried to connect my two games together in the lobby it errored and after looking at a lot of posts, of which none helped, i realised that my two games had both connected to different regions. This meant that the two games couldn't connect, so to fix this problem you go to your lobby code and put in the start function: PhotonNetwork.ConnectToRegion("your region")
Hope this helps someone